# Mysql trigger to enter the desired id

Tags: mysql

I have two mysql and sqlserver databases, I share the same data with each other, but in order not to have an id conflict I number each mysql bank = 2, sqlserver = 1, I would like the table id to be inserted by mysql, bank number + id of the order. For example:

```
mysql bank -> 2
auto_incremente cidade id -> 38
saved to cidade table primary key id = 238
```

So I made this code:

```
DELIMITER $

CREATE TRIGGER Tgr_Cidade_Insert AFTER INSERT
ON cidade
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN

declare @idString varchar(10);
declare @idInt int;
declare @idLast int;
declare @nomeCidade varchar(50);
declare @totalCaracteres int;

set @idInt = NEW.idCidade
set @idInt = @idInt - 1
set @idString = CONVERT(@idInt, char)
set @totalCaracteres =  LENGTH(@idString)
set @idString = SUBSTRING(@idString, 2, @totalCaracteres - 1)
set @idInt = CONVERT(@idString, int)
set @idInt = @idInt + 1
set @idString = '1'
set @idString = @idString + CONVERT(@idInt, varchar(10))
set @idInt = CONVERT(@idString, int)

set @idLast = NEW.idCidade
set @nomeCidade = NEW.nomeCidade

insert cidade(id_cidade, nome_cidade) values(@idInt, @nomeCidade)
delete from cidade where id_cidade = @idLast

END$

DELIMITER ;
```

So I'm trying to create a trigger, I've already created it on the sql server, now Mysql is missing, giving the following error:

```
MySQL Messages: Documentation

# 1064 - You have a syntax error in your SQL next to '@idString varchar (10);
declare @idInt int;
declare @idLast int;
declare @name 'on line 6
```

I would like to know the solution or if there is another tool for this problem.

Answer (score 0):

There are two types of variables. [Local variables](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/stored-program-variables.html) (the ones you declare) and [user defined variables](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/user-variables.html).

You're mixing the syntax of both. That's why you get a syntax error.

But instead of fixing that, I would suggest to not do, what you want to do.
Instead I recommend to store your values in two columns, an auto_increment column and a column that stores your "mysql bank".
When you want to get a string that combines the two, you simply do

```
SELECT CONCAT(bank_column, auto_increment_column), ...
```

You don't need a trigger. Spare yourself some trouble.

Comment: but how would you resolve the conflict of having the same id in two different databases?

Comment: Please elaborate on that. How are the servers related?

Comment: So I'm creating a webservice in which data is saved online (mysql), with android app saving directly online, but I use the sql server for the desktop app to save offline in case of internet loss, so the possibility that a conflict occurs from id primary key

Comment: Then I recommend to not mix different database brands. Have a look at SQL Server's Merge Replication. Here's a short explanation what it does (scroll to the bottom): https://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=169612&seqNum=2

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem using: auto_increment_increment and auto_increment_offset. thus:

```
auto_increment_increment = 10
auto_increment_offset = 2
```

Thus, the id will be filled out like this:

```
ID
2
12
22
32.
...
```